# DB2 and jRuby on Rails OS compatibility between Windows 7 and Linux

Tags: windows, linux, db2, jruby, compatibility

I have to developed a project that is using DB2 and jRuby on rails. It will be used on Linux platform when it is ready.

I want to know if I developed in using windows 7, I will get any problems when deploying it on Linux?

I want to use the topic ask a few questions about the used technologies too:

1. What is the official website for "jRuby on rails"?Why there is only a little information about this technology and the few video presentations and the only a book are made 4-5 years ago?
2. Has anyone knew about any jruby on rails and db2 tutorial or article?

The reason I am asking this questions too is because I want to read something more about these and to be updated about the fixes and new versions as I am really unfamiliar with these two technologies.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop Rails applications on Windows and made deployments into Tomcat on Linux servers without any problems.

About your other question, I agree with you, some times it feels like theres not much documentation JRuby oriented but at the end remember that JRuby its only Ruby running over the JVM.

This is the wiki for JRuby https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki and here is the official website http://jruby.org/.

Regarding a db2 tutorial I think you should try harder in Google.com there are some gems and more information on the web.